# reflect values to combo box from datagrid on Selection Changed event

Tags: wpf, vb.net-2010

I have a `combobox` and `textbox` using which values are filled into `DataGridView`for display purpose.
The `datagrid`uses `SelectionChanged` event.

I am Trying to reflect the same data (when the user moves keys up and down or on mouse click) onto the combobox and textbox on `SelectionChanged` event of datagrid

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged

combobox.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("DatabaseTable_ColumnName1").Value.ToString()

textbox.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("DatabaseTable_ColumnName2").Value.ToString()

End Sub
```

Above code works fine for textbox but not for combobox.
In case of combobox, it reflects data of initially selected row only and not the rest.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you have to use this code for combobox

```
combobox1.items.add('your string here')
```

in your situation would be like this :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged

combobox1.items.add(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("DatabaseTable_ColumnName1").Value.ToString())

textbox.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("DatabaseTable_ColumnName2").Value.ToString()

End Sub
```